# JQGrid count rows doesn't match Sql query

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have got 2 problem

First: When Page loading, record count is coming 500 from sql query, But as you can see in the picture there is only 10 rows

Second: I want to dynamic search without jqgrid's searching, how do I send my query to service

how do I solve thoose problems?

```
      $("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({            
            url: "Classlar/GridIslem.ashx",
            datatype: "json", 
            colNames: ["Alan 1", "Alan 2", "Alan 3","alan 4"," laan 5","Alan 6"],
            shrinkToFit: false,
            width: 925,
            height: 250,
            hidegrid: false,
            colModel: [
                { name: "Alan1", width: 200 },
                { name: "Alan2", width: 251 },
                { name: "Alan3", width: 252 },
                { name: "Alan4", width: 253 },
                { name: "Alan5", width: 254 },
                { name: "Alan6", width: 254 },
            ],
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            //recreateForm: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                 
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            caption: "--",
            loadonce: true,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: "0"
            },
        });
        $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
                {
                    edit: false,
                    add: false,
                    del: false,
                    search: false,
                }
         );
```

"{\"total\":10,\"records\":500,\"page\":1,\"rows\":[{\"Alan1\":\"1\",\"Alan2\":\"Dosya 1\",\"Alan3\":\"Evrak Adet 10\",\"Alan4\":\"Evrak Adet 10\",\"Alan5\":\"Evrak Adet 10\",\"Alan6\":\"Evrak Adet 10\"},{\"Alan1\":\"2\",\"Alan2\":\"Dosya 2\",\"Alan3\":\"Evrak Adet 10\",\"Alan4\":\"Evrak Adet 11\",\"Alan5\":\"Evrak Adet 12\",\"Alan6\":\"Evrak Adet 13\"} ]}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid was designed originally to be able to fill grid with server based data. The option `loadonce: true` was introduced later. So if you don't use `loadonce` (or if you use `loadonce: false`) the server is responsible for paging, sorting and filtering of the data. Every time if the user click on the column header to sort the data by the column or if the user fill searching toolbar the new request to the server will be sent. If the user change the number of rows per page (choose other value as 10 in the pager) the new request to the server will be also send. The options `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`, `_search` and typically filters. Default names of parameters which will be sent to the server can be chaneged by prmNames option of jqGrid (see the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3Aoptions)).